# Back to Back Histograms in R Studio

Tags: r

Hello I just started using R Studio and I need to make a **back-to-back histogram**

I loaded Hmisc package and have the histbackback(...) function.

My data is stored in mydata4 and looks like this:
          GPA   Gender
1       7.9        M
2       8.3        M
3       4.6        M
4       7.5        M
5       8.9        F
6       7.6        M
7       7.7        M
8       2.4        M
9       6.0        F

I need a back to back histogram of the GPAs for female and male students.

I've tried:

```
    histbackback(mydata4[1], mydata4[2]) 
    Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you probably need `histbackback(mydata[mydata$Gender=="M","GPA"],mydata[mydata$Gender=="F","GPA"])`